# How can I use tinygps with a ttl serial communication?

Tags: arduino, gps, libraries

I'm making a robot that follows you and I need to use tinygps library to communicate with the gps.  I have the adafruit ultimate gps and it uses ttl to communicate.

I'm going to use the tinygps.h for this project. It is available at https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPS

I would expect it to be able to give a coordinate of it's current location.

Any help would be apprecieated.

Thanks you.

Comment: Which Arduino board are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Arduino Uno.

Comment: What is your problem then? Have you tried [test_with_gps_device.ino](https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPS/blob/master/examples/test_with_gps_device/test_with_gps_device.ino)?

Comment: No but the program only said that it only needs one communication pin.  But the tll serials need 2

Comment: It doesn't matter you only need to receive data from GPS so you need to connect Tx pin of GPS to Rx pin of the Arduino, so leave the other pin unconnected.